# Change the permission of multiple files using the GUI

Tags: macos, permission

I am looking for a way to change the permission of multiple files using the GUI.
I tried to select all the files and hit show info in the right click context menu, but this opens multiple dialogs where I have to enter my admin password and then change the permission.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You *can* use Finder to change multiple files permissions. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> will open the *Multiple Item Info* panel that should set the permissions for all files that have been selected (it also gives you total file size, and lets set label colors too).

Otherwise you can select the folder the files you want to change are in, and use the regular get info window to set permissions on all containing files.

[image: Appling permissions to enclosed items...]

Comment: On my tests the permissions box was greyed out so I assumed it was not accessible, but even with the permission items greyed out they are still active and able to be changed.  Nice answer :)

Comment: Thanks Man!! you are super!!! BTW: you look like a movie hero!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [BatChmod](http://www.macchampion.com/arbysoft/BatchMod/Welcome.html) a free utility for changing file permissions. You can select a folder that contains the files you’re interested in, make the changes and apply those changes to all of the files in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

On Catalina, you can't use the above solutions. What you can do is select the folder in which all images are located, go to the usual get info and change permissions for the folder. Once you are done with that, click on the lock icon and get administrator access to change permissions. Once you enter your password, click on the small gear icon at the bottom of the get info window and select "Apply to enclosed items". Tested on Catalina.

Answer (score -1):

The Finder isnt able to natively change permissions of multiple selected files.

There is a 3rd party file manager application called [Folklift2](http://www.binarynights.com/) which does have the ability to do this (amongst other things).  It's $29.95, but probably worth every cent if you need to do this often.

If you want instructions on how to do this via the command line for free, let me know in the comments :)

**[Edit: I was wrong, it is possible - see answer from @Nilloc]**

Comment: Yes please let me know the command line way.. also can we make shell script like of file on mac (like we do on linux) so I can run it easily. Thanks :)